# ABAP throws "unknown type of class" error

Tags: abap

I´m creating an ABAP program which uses 2 different classes. The first class is for selection data and presenting an ALV report. The second one is to extract that data to an CSV file.
When i am trying to call those methods in START-OF-SELECTION, i´m getting an error which says that "        the type of "LCL_EXTRACTOR" is unknown".

I have the following code on my class definition:

```
CLASS lcl_extractor DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.

    METHODS: write_data IMPORTING t_talv TYPE ty_t_talv.

    METHODS constructor.

ENDCLASS.
```

On my start of selection I have:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.

  CALL METHOD main=>inicializacao.

  CALL METHOD lcl_extractor=>write_data( t_talv = t_talv ).
```

Can someone help me please to understand what I am doing wrong?

My classes are defined as:

```
CLASS main DEFINITION FINAL.

  PUBLIC SECTION.

    CLASS-METHODS inicializacao.
    CLASS-METHODS principal.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS main IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD inicializacao.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD principal.
  ENDMETHOD.

CLASS lcl_extractor DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.

    METHODS: write_data IMPORTING t_talv TYPE ty_t_talv.

    METHODS constructor.

ENDCLASS.

METHOD write_data.
ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

P.S: That t_talv table is the table which is presented on my ALV.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - i.e. it should compile.

Comment: I´m sorry, that wasn´t the case, I just thought the problem was in the calling part, and didn´t want to bore with to much unnecessary information. Thank you for your answer. I already editted with more information, I can provide the logic inside of the methods, but I know that part is working, so I´m not sure if it´s important or not to put that. Thank you one more time.. About the missing word "CLASS" i didn´t notice that i did´t put a space after ```` in the first line...

Answer (score 6):

You are calling method as static while it is defined as instance. Change the calling line to

```
NEW lcl_extractor( )->write_data( t_talv = t_talv ).
```

or make the method static.